# ApplicationHandleException variable in Delphi 5?

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I am trying to use `AsyncCalls` which *suppose* to work for Delphi 5 also.

Everything compiles and runs fine, if I comment the lines that call/use [`ApplicationHandleException`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_ApplicationHandleException.html) classes variable which Delphi 5 does not have (I'm not sure when it was introduced either).

> ```
> procedure TThreadPool.MainThreadWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
> begin
>   try
>     ...
>   except
>     if Assigned(ApplicationHandleException) then
>       ApplicationHandleException(Self); 
>   end;
> end;
> ```

I'm *almost* sure that in Delphi 5 the above should be:

```
  try
    ...
  except
      Application.HandleException(Self); 
  end;
```

But not sure what to do about this code:

> ```
> destructor TInternalAsyncCall.Destroy;
> begin
>   ...
>   // TAsyncCall.Destroy either already called Sync() or we are a "forgotten" async call
>   // and we need to handle the exception ourself by trying to throw it in the main thread
>   // or just ignoring it.
>   if FFatalException <> nil then
>   begin
>     if Assigned(ApplicationHandleException) and // <---
>        (ThreadPool.FMainThreadVclHandle <> 0) and IsWindow(ThreadPool.FMainThreadVclHandle) then
>       PostMessage(ThreadPool.FMainThreadVclHandle, WM_RAISEEXCEPTION, WPARAM(FFatalErrorAddr), LPARAM(FFatalException))
>     else
>       FFatalException.Free;
>   end;
>   inherited Destroy;
> end;
> ```

What could be the correct "translation" in Delphi 5? Should I simply ignore this variable since it does not exists? please advice.

Comment: "*I'm not sure when it was introduced*" - the `ApplicationHandleException` callback was introduced in Delphi 6, as part of the re-organization of the VCL to support CLX in Kylix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `TApplication.Create` there is this code which assigns to the `ApplicationHandleException` variable.

```
if not Assigned(System.Classes.ApplicationHandleException) then
  System.Classes.ApplicationHandleException := HandleException;
```

Now `HandleException` is really `Self.HandleException`, when you allow for the implicit `Self` target.

So yes, you can replace:

```
if Assigned(ApplicationHandleException) then
  ApplicationHandleException(Self);
```

with

```
if Assigned(Application) then
  Application.HandleException(Self);
```

In general then, for Delphi 5, you would replace

```
Assigned(ApplicationHandleException)
```

with

```
Assigned(Application)
```

Almost always it will be the case that `Assigned(Application)` evaluates to `True`, but you might be working in a non VCL setting, or perhaps the code executes before the global `Application` object is created, or after it is destroyed.

Comment: Thank you so much. your knowledge is outstanding!

Comment: BTW, do you know where else the `ApplicationHandleException` could be assigned by the framework? I mean, is it assigned differently for a service application for example? (just guessing...)

Comment: FMX application, `TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridgeRequestHandler.Create`, `TSockWebRequestHandler.Create`, `TApacheApplication.Create`, `TCGIFactory.Create`, `TWebApplication.Create`, `TISAPIApplication.Create`, `TAppletApplication.Run`. But not service applications it seems.

Comment: So it seems that `Application` in some cases will not work as designed. never mind I'll think about it when I get there :-P

Comment: You probably need to look at how exceptions are handled in those other application types in D5. Quite a few won't exist I suspect.